# Binding table row with click event

Tags: html, knockout.js

I am using knockout and when I have binded a click event on my table row. However, when I click on the row, it displays the following error:

```
function d(){if(0<arguments.length){if(!d.equalityComparer||!d.equalityComparer(c,arguments[0]))d.H(),c=arguments[0],d.G();return this}b.r.Wa(d);return c}
```

does anyone know why I am getting this error?

Here's my view for the table:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: customers">
                    <tr data-bind="click: $root.doSomething">     
                        <td data-bind="text: date"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text:staff"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: ftype"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: value"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: message"></td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

Here's my viewmodel:

```
doSomething: function(data) { 
    var self = this;      
    self.date(data.date);        
    self.staff(data.staff); 
    self.ftype(data.ftype);
               self.value(data.value);
               self.message(data.message);  

}
```

Comment: Can you post your viewmodel and also your html?

Comment: Alright,give me a min plz

Comment: Alright, plz look at my post again

Comment: Maybe you can get something in jsFiddle?  When $root.doSomething is called, the value of `this` will be the individual customer and not the root view model.  To test you can do `click: $root.doSomething.bind($root)` to see if that is the issue.

Comment: Ok it is better now but still incomplete to answer. What is inside customers? How do you fill it? How is self.date,  self.staff, etc. definied? You mentioned "when I click on the row, it displays the following error:" where you see this error? In the console? On the UI?

Comment: The error appears in the UI. Infact, in the same row that I clicked. The data in the row just dissapears and all I see is the error code.

Comment: customers is just a static array that I am using. It has data in it,ofcourse

Comment: Is that enough or do I still need to provide the code? Please let me know

Comment: @RPNiemeyer, I added the .bnd($root) but it still doesnt work

Comment: Best bet is to get something in jsFiddle

Comment: What you try together with the `$root.doSomething.bind($root)` is to change your assigments to `self.date(data.date()); self.staff(data.staff());` etc. note the addtional `()`

Comment: @nemesv,I went ahead and added the modifications you suggested and the error I was getting is now not showing up. However, I am getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'value' knockout-2.2.1.js:62
(anonymous function) knockout-2.2.1.js:62
b.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
v.handle

Comment: Please create and post a jsFiddle which reproduces your error! We can't debug your problems without seeing your code.

Comment: I can't seem to duplicate the code I want in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do the trick?

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: customers">
    <tr data-bind="click: function() {$root.doSomething($data);}">
```

Comment: let me check and I will get back to you in a min

Comment: Wish the trick would work man. It is not even populating the data in the table. Thanks for your input though.I Appreciate it.